# Android : White screen on app reload. How to avoid?

Tags: android, splash-screen

I've read every questions on this site about how to put a splash screen on app start-up to avoid the white screen problem.  However the white screen still pops-up when the app has been in the background for a while.  Is there anyway to either make it transparent or redirect the app to the splash screen if the app has been in the background for a while?

Comment: voted to close this, because this question does not permit a concrete answer... while I'd suggest to have a look here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle which might help understanding, why it behaves as it does.

Comment: Please add your supporting code from Activity and Manifest.

Comment: also this article appears relevant: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of the **white screen** which is because of android's cold start, and appears when the app loads to memory, you can add the following style item to your `AppTheme`.

```
 <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

Comment: Yep you solved it thx !  I wasn't too sure in which style to put it, so I putted it everywhere, could that be a problem? doesn't look like it for now at least